# Download a CSV file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am trying to download a CSV file and using the following code :

```
  var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
  anchor.css({display: 'none'}); 
  angular.element(document.body).append(anchor); 
  anchor.attr({
            href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(data),
            target: '_blank',
            download: 'customerdetails.csv'
              });
   var click = new MouseEvent('click', {
                 'view': window,
                 'bubbles': true,
                 'cancelable': true
              });
 anchor[0].dispatchEvent(click);
```

This is working in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. In Safari I am facing the following error:

```
'[object MouseEventConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new MouseEvent')
```

I tried using blob, but I ended up with the following error:

```
'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"})')
```

Comment: What version of Safari are you using ?